# How to distribute the server Load

Tags: c#, sql-server, server, asyncsocket, distributed-system

I'm trying to get my head around this...

I have an application composed of one Server(basically a N tier console application with TCP Async socket programming in C#), One MSSQL database and several clients.

Now the problem is thousands of clients is connecting to this server at the same time and server is not responding efficiently.I want to make this server as distributed and scalable to distribute the clients load.

I'm trying to figure out if there's solution to this problem.Any convenient solution is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Consider a load balancer, though with tcp sockets that would be pretty complicated. HAProxy is said to do tcp sockets: http://www.haproxy.org/

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the problem correctly, but can't you just have several servers and pick the one where it connects randomly?

Comment: Which one consumes more resources? SQL Server or the console app?. If the answer is SQL Server. Obviously, you would not get a great escalability improvement by load balancing the console app.

Comment: @SyedIftequar No I mean that the client just picks the server randomly and connects to it -- it's not as fancy as a load balancer but also a lot simpler (and most likely cheaper)

Comment: @JamesZ : you means there will be another main server (load balancer like what Zaitsman is suggesting ) which will assign IP/Port of multiple server instances to client randomly...?

FYI: My clients are mobile phones.They need socket details(IP/Port ) even to connect to the load balancer.

Thanks.

Comment: @Jesús López : Its Console application.

Comment: That is unusual. I would try to optimize the console app before throwing more hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a but slim on details, and this is not a drop-in solution: but I always steer clear of load balancers ( central point of failure, and you can only efficiently use the one datacenter or region ).

**The client is the load balancer**

instead, have a central endpoint to list the farmed servers, and then have the client randomly select a server to use for an amount of time. That selected server can then specialise on serving resources for that client, copying data from remote server(s) locally, if not already.

This selected server would be the master for that client, data would be created there and replicated to other servers later if the client changes server.

With such a distributed setup your servers can be deployed anywhere in the world generically. So your clients also get better latency and you can find the best priced hosting without being tied to a load balancer.

**Container Clustering**

You'll find clustering like coreos interesting but much more complicated to setup. But don't rule it out. For such a simple console application, it's not that hard to tweak your solution and control your own simpler scalable infrastructure with no extra layers of obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the server-application cluster able, so that you can start instances multiple times on different virtural or physical computer. Than i would chose one single computer to be a load balancer. A good tool for load balancing in your case is HAproxy. This proxy will balance the load of work on different server. This will bring you the optimum of performance.